# Dependency Injection in Angular 2 Child Component

Tags: angular

How do I do dependency injection for a child class in Angular 2 when the parent does not have the provider?

```
import { NgModule, Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { EntityrecordApi } from '../sdk/services/custom';
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { FormlyFieldSelect } from 'ng2-formly';

@Component({
  selector: 'formly-field-lookup-select',
  providers: [EntityrecordApi],
  template:'<div>Test</div>'
})

export class LookupSelect extends FormlyFieldSelect implements OnInit{
  constructor(@Inject(EntityrecordApi) private _EntityrecordApi: EntityrecordApi) {
   super()
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
   //Do Something here
    this._EntityrecordApi.find()
  }
}
```

[FormlyFieldSelect](https://github.com/formly-js/ng2-formly/blob/master/src/ui-bootstrap/types/select.ts)

In the above example , I always get _EntityrecordApi as undefined. Can you please help?

**Component Hierarchy Image in Augury**

[image]

Comment: Is your service marked as `@Injectable()`? Do you get any error messages in the console?

Comment: Also is `EntityrecordApi ` has been include in `providers` options of your `NgModule` metadata?

Comment: ya it is marked as @Injectable() and EntityrecordApi  has been included in the providers option

Answer (score 0):

Even if the parent class had the provider, you wouldn't get it. Decorators are not inherited in Angular 2.

You'll have to add the service to the `providers` of the component (if you want 1 instance of the service per instance of the component). or the module containing that component (if you want 1 instance of the service in the whole app).

Comment: hi Meligy, I have added the "EntityrecordApi" service to the providers of the component , but it comes as undefined in the constructor.

Comment: If I remove the  `extends FormlyFieldSelect` then I am able to get the provider in the constructor..

Comment: Sounds like something you can reproduce in a Plunker, would you be able to create a small sample of just the injection problem with inheritance?